# Jinja2 Split string by white spaces

Tags: string, split, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 template engine (+pelican).

I have a string saying "a 1", and I am looking for a way to split that string in two
by using the white-space as the delimiter.

So the end result I'm looking for is a variable which holds the two values in a form of an array. e.g. str[0] evaluates to "a" & str[1] evaluates to "1".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue and didn't find anything useful, so I just created a custom filter :

```
def split_space(string):
    return string.strip().split()
```

Added it to the filter list (with flask):

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def split_space(string):
    return string.strip().split()

#some code here

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.jinja_env.filters['split_space'] = split_space
    app.run()
```

And used it as such in the template :

```
{% if "string" in element|split_space %} ... {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 28):

Calling split on the string should do the trick:

```
"a 1".split()
```

Comment: @Loïc I think I've used something similar with Ansible which uses Jinja2. So maybe it depends? I'm not very sure about this.

Comment: Just confirming that {% for hostname in allowed_hosts.split() %} works fine. So I assume you could also do {% set hostnames=allowed_hosts.split() %}, but haven't tested the latter.

Comment: @MichaelNelson's latter method also works.

`{% for instance in instances %}
  {% set route_name=instance.split(' ')[1] %}
  BalancerMember http://{{ instance }} route={{ route_name }}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Does anyone know where split() is documented? Darned if I couldn't find it.

Comment: @MatthewCornell you mean this https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split ?

Comment: @jkbkot Doh! I was stuck thinking *nothing* made it through to templates :-O

Comment: Good trick that others may find helpful. Imagine a string "AAA BBB" and you only want to display the "AAA" part in the template. Use this syntax: ```{{ target_string.split()[0] }}```. Key for stripping off the HH/MM/SS from timestamps in templates at the last moment, for example.

Answer (score 4):

my solution is tested in iPython

```
In [1]: from jinja2 import Template
In [2]: Template("{{s.split('-')}}").render(s='a-bad-string')
Out[2]: u"['a', 'bad', 'string']"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use something like:

```
str = "a 1 b 2 c 3"
val = atr.split()
```

Also, if you want to point a specific position then you can use something like:

```
val1 = atr.split()[2]
```

This will put second value in `val1`.

Answer (score 3):

I made a little plugin that does the same as Loïc's answer but it optionally specifying a separator. https://github.com/timraasveld/ansible-string-split-filter

It allows you to type:

```
# my_variable = 'a 1`
{ my_variable | split | join(' and ') } #=> a and 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a decorator:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter('split_space')
def split_space_filter(s):
    return s.strip().split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```