# Split string into list in jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have some variables in a jinja2 template which are strings seperated by a ';'.

I need to use these strings separately in the code.
i.e. the variable is variable1 = "green;blue"

```
{% list1 = {{ variable1 }}.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ list1[0] }} and the boat is {{ list1[1] }}
```

I can split them up before rendering the template but since it are sometimes up to 10 strings inside the string this gets messy.

I had a jsp before where I did:

```
<% String[] list1 = val.get("variable1").split(";");%>    
The grass is <%= list1[0] %> and the boat is <%= list1[1] %>
```

EDIT:

It works with:

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ list1[0] }} and the boat is {{ list1[1] }}
```

Comment: CAn you split the string before sending it to the template?

Comment: @IanAuld yes I can but like I said it gets messy because it are a lot of strings and they all contain a lot of strings inside them.

Comment: You could write your own filter to do a split on whatever character you like. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678004/jinja2-split-string-by-white-spaces

Answer (score 206, accepted):

After coming back to my own question after 5 year and seeing so many people found this useful, a little update.

A string variable can be split into a `list` by using the split function (it can contain similar values, `set` is for the [assignment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#assignments)) . I haven't found this function in the official documentation but it works similar to normal Python. The items can be called via an index, used in a loop or like Dave suggested if you know the values, it can set variables like a tuple.

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ list1[0] }} and the boat is {{ list1[1] }}
```

or

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
{% for item in list1 %}
    <p>{{ item }}<p/>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% set item1, item2 = variable1.split(';') %}
The grass is {{ item1 }} and the boat is {{ item2 }}
```

Comment: Jinja2 will also assign expanded-tuple style ala `{% set list1,list2 = variable1.split(';') %}`.

Comment: Is this a list or a set? Because in set, it will follow the properties of the set and not the list.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal the value which is passed into the template is a semicolon seperated string.

Comment: Yes, but we created list1, then whether it is a list or a set?

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal I think the split function creates list. the 'set' is from settting a variable not dataset. But I'm not sure if it is list or set, but you can just get to your data with {{ list1[0] }}.

Comment: " I haven't found this function in the official documentation" such a shame. I do think that Jinja has the worst documentation even ! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The `split` function is the one present in string objects (all string methods are available from jinja2 templates?): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

Comment: @emi it works because of https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#python-methods :


`Python Methods

You can also use any of the methods defined on a variable’s type. The value returned from the method invocation is used as the value of the expression. Here is an example that uses methods defined on strings (where page.title is a string):

{{ page.title.capitalize() }}`

Answer (score 22):

If there are up to 10 strings then you should use a list in order to iterate through all values.

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
{% for list in list1 %}
<p>{{ list }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can’t run arbitrary Python code in jinja; it doesn’t work like JSP in that regard (it just looks similar). All the things in jinja are custom syntax.

For your purpose, it would make most sense to define a [custom filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/api/#custom-filters), so you could for example do the following:

```
The grass is {{ variable1 | splitpart(0, ',') }} and the boat is {{  splitpart(1, ',') }}
Or just:
The grass is {{ variable1 | splitpart(0) }} and the boat is {{  splitpart(1) }}
```

The filter function could then look like this:

```
def splitpart (value, index, char = ','):
    return value.split(char)[index]
```

An alternative, which might make even more sense, would be to split it in the controller and pass the splitted list to the view.

Comment: Where do I put the filter function?

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich Did you read the documentation about custom filters that I linked in my answer?

Comment: I did - and that's why I asked. I'm using this in the context of Ansible and so have found a more relevant answer. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/A7fGX-7X-ks thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to define a custom filter. In flask's version of jinja it looks like this:

```py
@app.template_filter("split")
def split(value: str, separator=" ", maxsplit: int = -1):
    return value.split(separator, maxsplit)
```

And without flask it can be done similarly:

```py
def split(value: str, separator=" ", maxsplit: int = -1):
    return value.split(separator, maxsplit)

environment.filters["split"] = split
```

Usage:

```
{{ commit.message | split }}
```