# Django: How to get the first word of a string in an HTML template?

Tags: django, jinja2

### Problem

I am passing a list to my HTML template and the list looks like this:

```
Chemical Engineering
Civil Engineering
Computer Engineering
Electrical Engineering
Electronics Engineering
...
```

### My Goal

I want to grab the first word (I would like to remove the "engineering" in all of them). I'm displaying the list in my HTML template like this:

```
{% for course in courses %}
    <li>{{ course }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

### What I tried

I tried the following syntax:

```
{% for course in courses %}
    <li>{{ course.split[0] }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% for course in courses %}
    <li>{{ course[0] }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% for course in courses %}
    <li>{{ course|first }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The third one above only gives me the first letter of each string. I know that I can do truncate but not all of them have the same number of characters. I also tried to do
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515456/split-string-into-list-in-jinja) but to no avail. Maybe my syntax was wrong? What other solutions can I try? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your `course` is a string type, and the `first` would give you the first letter. that's expected. You need to somehow make course a list consist of 2 words first. You can either do it in the backend or create a custom filter for that. Essentially it does `your_string.split(' ')`

Comment: In the template you should be able to do: `course.split.0` to get the first token. At least in the django templating engine. With jinja2, I am not sure, but it is even less restricting.

Comment: Thanks schwobaseggl! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [schwobaseggl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) comment, he mentioned trying the syntax `course.split.0` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
{% for course in courses %}
{% set words = course.split(' ') %}
<li>{{ words[0] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```