# Ansible Jinja2 template splitting a string into Key value pair

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Below is my string value in Jinja2 and Ansible

```
studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD
```

Can I change it to dictionary so i can use my jinja2 template as below

```
student id=item.studId
student name= item.studName
```

Output expected is

```
student id=ValueA
student name= ValueB
student id=ValueC
student name= ValueD
```

Comment: Your expected output contains duplicate keys, which cannot be the contents of a dict.

Comment: You could use split to get a list, and then split the elements again...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515456/split-string-into-list-in-jinja

Comment: I have tried earlier. The list it state does not support split method

Answer (score 0):

Given the string

```yaml
    s1: studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD
```

unify the separators, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        s2: "{{ s1|regex_replace('[,;]', ';') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    s2: studId=ValueA;studName=valueB;studId=ValueC;studName=ValueD
```

Split the items, iterate them by 2 items, and create the list of the dictionaries, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ l1|d([]) + [dict(item|map('split', '='))] }}"
      loop: "{{ s2.split(';')|batch(2) }}"
```

gives the expected structure of the data

```yaml
  l1:
  - studId: ValueA
    studName: valueB
  - studId: ValueC
    studName: ValueD
```

Now, the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for item in l1 %}
          student id={{ item.studId }}
          student name={{ item.studName }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  msg: |-
    student id=ValueA
    student name=valueB
    student id=ValueC
    student name=ValueD
```

Comment: this can be done for more thank 1 list sir. fo now i show 2, cn it be done more than 2. can it done in jinja2 template